# Como enviar uma requisição POST sem formulário

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código.Retirado deste  [site](https://viniciusmuniz.com/pt/como-enviar-uma-requisicao-post-sem-formulario/). Quero enviar os valores descritos abaixo ,para outra pagina através de POST(Sem usar formulário nem AJAX).Minha duvida é como faço para recuperar os valores na outra pagina e o que exatamente este método (file_get_contents )  faz.

```
$content = http_build_query(array(
    'field1' => 'Value1',
    'field2' => 'Value2',
    'field3' => 'Value3',
));

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $content,
    )
));

$result = file_get_contents('http://exemplo/make_action.php', null, $context);

$content = http_build_query(array(
    'field1' => 'Value1',
    'field2' => 'Value2',
    'field3' => 'Value3',
));

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $content,
    )
));


$result = file_get_contents('http://exemplo/make_action.php', null, $context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recuperação do valores na outra página será feita da forma habitual, como se estivesse usando formulários.

```
<?php
echo 'Valor1: '.$_POST['field1'];
?>
```

Esse seria o código presente `http://exemplo/make_action.php`.

Você encontra a explicação do método file_get_contents em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php , em resumo, essa função lê um arquivo e retorna uma String. Então no seu exemplo, ele irá ler a página `http://exemplo/make_action.php` passando os parâmetros em `$context` e retornará a página processada colocando na variável `$result`.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas complementando a resposta já dada acima, uso desta forma:

```
//Por segurança, para pegar só o desejado, sem tags html
$Antes = "/[><']/";//Html, para retirar
$Depois = " ";

if(isset($_POST['valor'])){
$x_valor = preg_replace($Antes,$Depois,$_POST['valor']);
}else{
$x_valor = "";//Pega vazio se não vier como esperado
}

echo "$x_valor";

?>
```